# Memory Error with pandas when convert dict to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, out-of-memory

i have a dictionary variable with almost 70K X 70K dimension, i want to convert it to Dataframe for further operation by

```
wd=pd.DataFrame(wordDict)
```

but after 5 min working it give me follow error:

```
subarr=np.empty(len(),dtype=dtyp)
Memory Error
```

i could find some post about it, **but it seems that it is a common problem with pandas and Numpy library and unfortunately nobody could provide concrete answer**, mostly they advise to slice the dataset and feed it in two or three steps.

just i raise this issue again with hope that maybe the library get some updata to fix it or **maybe there is some technique** to overcome on this.

**as wrap up**; is it a bug? and is there any alternative solution **to convert dictionary to dataframe**
thank you

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug.

An array of size 70k x 70k means **4.9 billion** variables that need to be stored in a dataframe.

Dataframes have overheads relative to objects such as dictionaries and lists. So you will need *more than twice* the memory used by the dictionary to build the dataframe.

You need to consider another way of using your data. Some examples:

- Use HDF5 to write data to a file lazily and then read out-of-memory.
- Store data in a csv file written lazily, read & filter in chunks to reduce memory consumption.
- Store data in a csv file written lazily, read & filter via `dask.dataframe`.

You have not provided specifics in your question for us to advise further.